# Flush INET Socket response data with BLOCKING enabled

Tags: perl, sockets

I am making a program that interfaces with Teamspeak, and I have an issue where the responses received will not match the commands sent. I run the program multiple times and each time, I will get different results when they should be the same, due to responses being out of sync.

```
my $buf = '';
use IO::Socket; 
my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerAddr => 'localhost'
    ,PeerPort => '10011'
    ,Proto => 'tcp'
    ,Autoflush   => 1
    ,Blocking    => 1
    ,Timeout    => 10
    ); 

sub ExecuteCommand{
    print $sock $_[0]."\n";$sock->sysread($buf,1024*10);
    return $buf;
};

ExecuteCommand("login ${username} ${password}");
ExecuteCommand("use sid=1");
ExecuteCommand("clientupdate client_nickname=Idle\\sTimer");
my $client_list = ExecuteCommand("clientlist");
```

Each command is executed properly, however the server likes to return extra lines, so a single sysread will not be enough and I will have to execute another. The size of responses are at most 512, so they aren't being cut off. If I try to run the sysread multiple times in an attempt to flush it, when there is nothing to read it will just make the program hang.

The end of the executions are followed with "error id=0 msg=ok"

How would I be able to read all the data that comes out, even if it's multiple lines? Or just be able to flush it all out so I can move onto the next command without having to worry about old data?

Comment: I am running a loop that checks each client from the list generated from clientlist, but I get things that aren't part of the list.

So if I `print ExecuteCommand("clientinfo clid=1")`, then followed with `print ExecuteCommand("clientinfo clid=2")`, instead of getting the clientinfo I'll get "error code=0". If I then run `$sock->sysread($buf,1024*10);print $buf;` I will get the clientinfo from clid=2

Answer (score 0):

So you want to read until you find a line starting with `error`. In addition to doing that, the following buffers anything extra read since it's part of the next response.

```
sub read_response {
   my ($conn) = @_;

   my $fh               =   $conn->{fh};
   our $buf; local *buf = \($conn->{buf});  # alias
   our $eof; local *eof = \($conn->{eof});  # alias

   $buf = '' if !defined($buf);

   return undef if $eof;

   while (1) {
      if ($buf =~ s/\A(.*?^error[^\n]*\n)//ms) {
         return $1;
      }

      my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
      if (!$rv) {
         if (defined($rv)) {
            $eof = 1;
            return undef;
         } else {
            die "Can't read response: $!\n";
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
my $conn = { fh => $sock };

... send command ...
my $response = read_response($conn);
...

... send command ...
my $response = read_response($conn);
...
```

Comment: Did I do this right? `sub ExecuteCommand{ print $sock $_[0]."\n";return read_response($conn);};` Because now it hangs, just like when I try to read a response that doesn't exist (due to Blocking = 1).

Comment: Oh I changed the error matching to `$buf =~ /error id=([0-9]{1,})/i` and it works. However, I now just a zero for my response.

Comment: Haha I just understood your code, I changed it back to what it was. But I am still getting the hang after it first executes.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the error was at the start of a line. Just remove the `^` if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `ExecuteCommand` subroutine to include a check for "error code=[0-9]{1,}", which is what is always at the end of a response for Teamspeak 3 servers.

```
sub ExecuteCommand{
    print $sock $_[0]."\n";
    my $response = "";
    while (1){
        $sock->sysread($buf,1024*10);
        last if($buf =~ /error id=([0-9]{1,})/);
        $response .= $buf;
    };
    return $response;
};
```